# Kendo Custom validation no decimals

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to a custom validation message so that users cannot enter decimals points.

kendo fields:

```
field: `minValue`,

title: `Test Number TextBox`,

format: "{0:c0}", //c0 displays without cents, c will display cents  

schema: {
         model: {
                 id : "id",
                 fields: {
                         id: { editable: false, type: 'number'},
                         name: { editable: true, type : "string" },
                         value: {type : "number", validation: {
                                                    required: true,
                                                    validateTitle: function (input) {

                                                        if (input.val().pattern == #.0) {
                                                           input.attr("data-validatevalue-msg", "May not enter decimals");
                                                           return false;
                                                        }    

                                                        return true;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Kendo has built in support for that, simply set decimals to 0.

Comment: I have that set and that does not work. It still allows me to enter decimals in the numeric text box.

Comment: e.container.find("input[name='minValue']").attr("data-k-decimals", "0");

Comment: field: "minValue",
                    title: "Minimum Value",
                    width: '150px',
                    decimals: 0,
                    step: 1,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 10000000000000000,
                    format: "{0:c0}", //c0 displays without cents, c will display cents  
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    },

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/IkonOK demonstrates a currency numeric textbox with decimals set to 0 and it won't accept a decimal point. I thought the ASP.Net version has the same capabilities, but I would ask a question to Telerik support if you can't get it to work. Might also depend on which version you're using? Not sure.